# What is the downside to using the Visual Studio Express Editions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm developing an application using Visual C# Express Edition - what is the downside to using the express editions?  Are there any limitations on what I can build and release?  Will my users be able to tell I'm using the Express Edition?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It won't impact your users, other than by making *you* less productive by prohibiting add-ons such as [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper), [TestDriven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net/), etc. and not having some of the built-in features of the commercial editions.

To put it another way: if a word processor didn't have a spell checker, you could still make sure that your documents were spelled correctly, so readers wouldn't know - but it's a lot quicker (usually!) if the tool has it built in...

Comment: Spot on Jon... this is one of the biggest "missing" feature on VS Express editions.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a huge comparison chart of all versions of Visual Studio, from Express until Team System.

[Visual Studio 2008 Product Comparison Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=727BCFB0-B575-47AB-9FD8-4EE067BB3A37&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 10):

- No AddIns whatsoever - no ReSharper, no [TestDriven.net](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2007/05/30/microsoft-vs-testdriven-net-express.aspx), no VisualSVN, no nothing
- Server Explorer does not support remote databases
- No support for solution folders
- <strike>Express targets only a single Framework - Express 2008 targets .net 3.5 only.</strike> (Edit: I was wrong, Express 2008 indeed supports multi-targeting)
- Reinstalling Express may require re-registration which is free, but can be shut down any time from Microsoft

Apart from that, it's fine. It uses the same compiler to generate the same code, you just don't get all the Time-Saving tools that VS Professional offers.

Comment: The comparison chart says that express editions have multi-targetting support as well

Comment: If you download and install the ISO version registration is not required for continued use.

Answer (score 7):

The Express debugger [does not allow Attach to Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express):

> The ability to attach the debugger to
>   an already-running process has also
>   been removed, hindering scenarios such
>   as writing Windows services and
>   re-attaching a debugger under ASP.NET
>   when errors under the original
>   debugging session cause breakpoints to
>   be ignored.

I can live with everything else but that.

Comment: This is not true, VS Express has roughly the same debugger as the full version (maybe with less features, I'm not sure...)

Comment: I corrected the comment to be specific to Attach to Process not working for web applications. I do a lot of SharePoint development and not having Attach to Process makes it unusable. If someone knows of a way to get Attach to Process to work, please post a link.

Answer (score 3):

See [features and tools available with Express editions, Visual Studio Standard and Professional editions, and Visual Studio Tools for Office.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcbsd3cz(VS.80).aspx)

It has no mobile device support - one of the most important features, for me :o)

Answer (score 3):

Only one language is supported. You can't have an application in C# and a library in C++ in the same solution, for instance.

Also, third party ADO.NET providers are not supported in the designers

Comment: Indeed, this is generally the turning point that forces me to use a non-express edition.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Express can do "most" of what the higher editions can do until you start getting into more advanced things such as trying to install third-party components and get full integration, adding database projects, integration into third-party systems, etc. On that note even Visual Studio Standard lacks several of these features so you'd be looking at Professional (at a minimum) to get a fully robust and feature-rich edition.

Answer (score 0):

No MFC visual gui builder for C++.

EDIT

Oops - just read the C# tag.  I'll leave this up though in case it comes up in a search for anyone else who might also be using c++

Answer (score 0):

The current version of VS Express (I'm writing in 2014) has no diagnostics. No assert method and things like stat monitoring. For me this means I'll use a different version to finish a site because it limits testing and validation. No point in making a sub-par .NET site to be actually used.